# how to select multiple lines in iphone .plist file?

Tags: iphone, select, lines

In my Iphone application ,i am using .plist file having so many data.
I want to select multiple lines in .plist file.

Please give any key combination by using which i can select multiple lines in .plist file and also use it for my own purpose.

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 8):

The view you get in xcode doesnt allow multiple row select. You can right click the plist and "open as" plain text though and copy the raw xml.

Comment: More specifically, the view you are looking at in xcode is 'Property List'. If you right click on the plist file, you can then open as 'Source Code'. Now you can edit the file. When done with your edit, right click on the file again and open as 'Property List' to restore your normal view of the plist